# Using ConvertTableToCsvFile tool with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, csv, arcgis-10.4

I would like to export a table from a geodatabase to a csv file with the ConvertTableToCsvFile tool. I have read through the [esri help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/tools/roads-and-highways-toolbox/convert-table-to-csv-file.htm) and adapted the code for my purpose:

```
import arcpy, os

### Set project path
project_path = r"C:\Users\..."
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

### Set current directory
gdb = project_path + "data/raw/ACS/ACS_2014_5YR_BG_06_CALIFORNIA.gdb/" 
out = project_path + "data/ACS/"

### Convert to csv
    arcpy.ConvertTableToCsvFile_locref(gdb + "X14_SCHOOL_ENROLLMENT", out + "X14_SCHOOL_ENROLLMENT", "COMMA")
```

However, I get the error that

> the 'module' object has no attribute 'ConvertTableToCsvFile_locref'.

What do I do wrong? I have looked for similar questions but apparently the problem is so trivial that noone would ask. (I am still a beginner with ArcPy and Python.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Convert Table to CSV File* tool requires the *[Esri Roads and Highways](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/roads-and-highways/what-is-roads-and-highways.htm)* extension and the *[Location Referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/location-referencing-roads-toolbox/location-referencing-toolbox-licensing.htm)* toolbox.

If you do not have this extension enabled and the toolbox installed, arcpy will report that it can't find the tool.

```
the 'module' object has no attribute 'ConvertTableToCsvFile_locref'.
```

The `_locref` at the end of the tool name is referring to the *Location Referencing* toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

While Midavalo's answer is the correct response to the question posed by me, the following workaround solves the problem:

Instead of `arcpy.ConvertTableToCsvFile_locref()` it is much easier to use the `arcpy.TableToTable_conversion()` tool instead. The revised code works perfectly:

```
import arcpy, os

### Set project path
project_path = r"C:\Users\..."
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

### Set current directory
gdb = project_path + "data/raw/ACS/ACS_2014_5YR_BG_06_CALIFORNIA.gdb/" 
out = project_path + "data/ACS/"
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(gdb + "X14_SCHOOL_ENROLLMENT", out, "X14_SCHOOL_ENROLLMENT.csv")
```

Credits again to Midavalo for the suggestion to use the table to table conversion tool.